# how sum function in python works with this case (adding up tuples of a list)

Tags: python, sum

I am trying to use sum() function in my code, but there is an error, which i did not understand why. How can i solve this problem

my code should add up tuples of a list so the output should be like this

the input:

a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]

the output:

(5, 7, 9)

this is my code

```
a = [(1, 3, 5), (2, 3, 5), (3, 3, 5), (4, 3, 5)]
a = iter(a)
b = next(a)
for x in a:
    b = sum(b, x)
print(b)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using the `zip` builtin function:

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]
```

Full console session:

```
>>> a = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> list(zip(*a))  # "Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables"
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]
[5, 7, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanx a lot it was very helpfull

Comment: You're very welcome. Do you mind accepting the answer so that others can see that your question has been solved? Thats the checkmark next to the voting buttons.